# unable to send response to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I have a AJAX request is on click of a button which takes values of two text fields in the page like:

```
$('.result-btn').on('click', function() {
 var field1= $('#f1').val();
 var field2= $('#f2').val();
 var data = {
     "f1": field1,
     "f2": field2
 };

 $.ajax({
     url: '/result',
     type: 'POST',
     data: JSON.stringify(data),
     contentType: 'application/json',
     success: function(data) {
         console.log('keyword transfer successful!\n');
     },
 });

});
```

In my routes.js i have this route defined :

```
import TestController from './controllers/TestController';
export default {
'/result': {
post: {
  method: TestController.getResults, //This is the async function 
  public: true,
  },
 },
};
```

I have a async function that is called after an AJAX request like this :

```
async function getResults(req,res){
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body)); //correctly outputs to the console
res.json(req.body); // I want to send this to the client
}
```

Now it correctly outputs to the console but doesnt sends anything to the client.Why is it so ?

Comment: Have you checked your console for any errors? Any sort of output?

Comment: Is the button in a form and page is reloading?

Comment: @MikeC No errors,i get the "console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))" this output  in console which is a sort of mapping of fieldname and filed value entered by user.

Comment: @charlietfl no there is no form encapsulation of the button,only ajax request is there on click of button which completes and i get field value pair.but now i want to send this to my browser and show it,but i get no output.

Comment: This is tagged `Express`, but I don’t recognize the way you are defining `routes.js`. Is that some other framework?